# VLC Timestamp export to notepad/excel via button

Tags: excel, timestamp, vlc, notepad

I'm working on analyzing traffic flow on 3 different bus stops as a research by watching recordings of it on VLC; I need to write down real-world timestamp of every bus stop and go along with a number of passengers boarding and exiting bus.
I'm looking for a way to speed things up by maybe using some kind of plugin in VLC player that would allow me to mark all these events with bound hotkey(s) and later export it to Excel/Notepad using offset time (I know the start time of recording, so I would export them in Excel with offset value in comparison to real-world timestamp). Timestamp format is hh:mm:ss, is there any way for this to work?

Comment: You question is far too board. To do that, it involves building a plugin for VLC, which will first provide an UI for user input, then write result in either Excel or plain text format.

Comment: Look for software used for `transcription`, pretty much all of them should have the ability to extract the current time-stamp using a function key.